# Perfomance issues on navigation through Bottom Navigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm handling darkmode toggling in a react native app and I have to pass the darkmode/lightmode styles as props to screens that are navigated through the `BottomTabNavigator`but the  issue is the navigation process from one bottom tab to another is very slow( This has happened after passing the props to those respective screens)

I'm using :

```
 react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
 react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
 react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
 react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12"
```

My `BottomTabs.js` code

```
const BottomTabs = () => {
  const { isDarkModeEnabled } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

  const screenStyle = isDarkModeEnabled
    ? {
        backgroundColor: "#050C12",
        color: "#FFFAF0", // Text color for dark mode
        iconColor: "#FFFFFF", // Icon color for dark mode
      }
    : {
        backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8",
        color: "black", // Text color for light mode
        iconColor: "black", // Icon color for light mode
      };

  const tabBarStyle = isDarkModeEnabled
    ? {
        backgroundColor: "#101E2A",
        color: "#FFFAF0", // Text color for dark mode
        iconColor: "#FFFFFF", // Icon color for dark mode
      }
    : {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        color: "black", // Text color for light mode
        iconColor: "black", // Icon color for light mode
      };

  const cardStyle = isDarkModeEnabled
    ? {
        cardBackgroundColor: "#101E2A",
        cardColor: "#FFFAF0",
        cardIconColor: "#D9E6F2",
      }
    : {
        cardBackgroundColor: "white",
        cardColor: "#101010",
        cardIconColor: "#101010",
      };

  const statsCardStyle = isDarkModeEnabled
    ? {
        cardBackgroundColor: "tomato",
        cardColor: "#FFFAF0",
      }
    : {
        cardBackgroundColor: "tomato",
        cardColor: "#101010",
      };

  //popular league card styling on dark mode toggling
  const popularLeagueCardStyle = isDarkModeEnabled
    ? {
        cardBackgroundColor: "#101E2A",
        cardColor: "#FFFAF0",
      }
    : {
        cardBackgroundColor: "white",
      };

  return (
    <BottomTab.Navigator>
   <BottomTab.Screen name="Home" options={{ 
    headerShown: false }}>
        {(props) => (
        <View
         style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 
         tabBarStyle.backgroundColor }}
          >
          <TopTabNavigator
              {...props}
              screenStyle={screenStyle}
              cardStyle={cardStyle}
              popularLeagueCardStyle={popularLeagueCardStyle}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </BottomTab.Screen>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Stats"
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: cardStyle.cardBackgroundColor,
          },
          headerTitleStyle: { color: screenStyle.color },
        }}
      >
        {(props) => (
          <Stats
            {...props}
            screenStyle={screenStyle}
            cardStyle={statsCardStyle}
            popularLeagueCardStyle= 
       {popularLeagueCardStyle}
          />
        )}
      </BottomTab.Screen>
      <BottomTab.Screen
        name="Settings"
        options={{
          headerStyle: screenStyle, // Apply the 
         screenStyle to headerStyle
          headerTitleStyle: { color: screenStyle.color 
       },
        }}
        component={SettingsScreen}
      />
    </BottomTab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Sample Bottom tab screen ( `Stats.js`) code

```
export default function Stats({cardStyle, screenStyle,popularLeagueCardStyle}) {
 const { backgroundColor, color, iconColor } = screenStyle;
  const { cardBackgroundColor, cardColor, cardiconColor } = cardStyle;
  const { popularCardBackgroundColor  } = popularLeagueCardStyle;

return(
  <View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor:backgroundColor}]}>
// some views rendered
</View>
);

}
```

So, when navigating through the stats,setting and other  Bottom tabs screen,the process is very slow. Please help

Comment: try creating a release build. It should fix as for development there are many things going on. So they may slow down it.